# Nanostore compiler issues on iOS

Tags: ios, sdk

I added the NanoStore Distribution directory to my project, and made sure the files are checked for Target Membership but I get this compiler error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-

L/Users/George/[REDACTED PROJECT NAME]/NanoStore2/Release/Library'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_llvm_gcda_emit_function", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoStore.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoGlobals.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoBag.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoEngine.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoObject.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoSearch.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFOrderedDictionary.o)
      ...
  "_llvm_gcda_emit_arcs", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoStore.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoGlobals.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoBag.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoEngine.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoObject.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoSearch.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFOrderedDictionary.o)
      ...
  "_llvm_gcda_start_file", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoStore.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoGlobals.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoBag.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoEngine.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoObject.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoSearch.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFOrderedDictionary.o)
      ...
  "_llvm_gcda_end_file", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoStore.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoGlobals.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoBag.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoEngine.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoObject.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFNanoSearch.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libnanostore2.a(NSFOrderedDictionary.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I cant seem to figure out whats wrong?

This is what it looks like in my project navigator: [image]

Comment: Which architectures are you building for and where did the library file come from? One guess is that the .a contains only the armv7s (iPhone 5 +) architecture and omits armv7 (iPhone 3GS +).

Comment: I was also getting a similar error until I added a reference to **libsqlite3.dylib** to my xcode project and then it suddenly worked.